# Interfaz gráfica para control de calificaciones

Tags: python, tkinter

Junto con saludar y esperando se encuentren bien junto a sus familias, les comento, estoy recién realizando un curso de Python y me dieron una tarea como proyecto final, como no tengo experiencia en programación me ha costado mucho crear el script, debo generar un script que me arroje por intermedio de una interfaz gráfica el promedio final de 5 notas, logre crear 4 funciones(calcular_Promedio(), endex(), validar_dato(x), verificar_rango(n)), cada una de ellas funcionan correctamente pero sin interfaz gráfica, las 5 notas las ingreso por teclado, valido la información ingresada y me arroja el promedio final correctamente, pero a la hora de crear una nueva función llamada Interfaz_Grafica() para que me muestre el promedio final se me cae el programa, cree un Button y le pase como parámetro la función calcular_Promedio() pero me arroja cualquier información menos el resultado correcto, no me manejo con interfaces gráficas, estoy trabajando con el modulo tkinter, lo único que debe mostrarme la interfaz gráfica es el mensaje si el alumno aprobó o reprobó la asignatura junto con el valor numérico del promedio final, agradecería mucho su ayuda debido a que no tengo experiencia con Python, muchas gracias.

##Este es mi script.

```
import sys
from tkinter import *

def Interfaz_Grafica():

    

    raiz = Tk() 
    raiz.geometry("200x200")
    raiz.resizable(0, 0)
    raiz.title("Interfaz gráfica para control de calificaciones")
    raiz.config(bg="White")
    miFrame=Frame() 
    miFrame.pack()
    miFrame.config(bg="White") 
    miFrame.config(width="150", height="50") 
   
    Button(raiz, text="Calcular el promedio", command = calcular_Promedio).pack()
    
    
    raiz.mainloop()


def calcular_Promedio():
    
    num_notas = 0
    suma_notas = 0
    nota = 0

    for num_notas in range(0,5):

        nota = input('Ingrese el valor de la nota: ')
        nota = validar_dato(nota)
        nota = verificar_rango(nota)
    
        num_notas += 1
        suma_notas += nota
        promedio_final = suma_notas / num_notas
    if (promedio_final >= 4):
        print('El alumno aprobo la asignatura con un promedio de {}'.format(promedio_final) )
    
    elif (promedio_final < 4):
        print('El alumno reprobo la asignatura con un promedio de {}'.format(promedio_final))
    
def endex():  

        print('Ejecuta nuevamente el programa')
        sys.exit() 

def validar_dato(x): 

    try : 
        
        return eval(x)
    except: 
        print('Dato ingresado no válido!')
    endex() 

def verificar_rango(n):
    
    try:
        if n > 0 and n <= 7:
            return (n)
        else:
            print('Nota fuera de rango')
            
    except:
        print()
    endex()

Interfaz_Grafica()
calcular_Promedio()
```

Comment: A ver si entendí, quieres que se ejecuta primera las consultas de datos, y luego se abra una ventana (interfaz gráfica) mostrando los resultados?

Comment: Así es estimado, yo ingreso por teclado 5 notas o números, después la función calcular_Promedio() realizara las operaciones correspondientes para darme como resultado el promedio final, necesito crear una interfaz gráfica que me muestre un mensaje de que si el alumno aprobó o reprobó la asignatura(dicho mensaje dependerá del valor del promedio), y que la interfaz gráfica también me muestre el valor del promedio de notas.

Comment: Checkea mi respuesta ;)

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el [`kwarg`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#keyword-arguments) `command` define la función que se va a **ejecutar** al presionar dicho botón. Creo que lo que estabas buscando es acceder al valor que **retorna**. Esto último tampoco tiene sentido ya que tu función no estaba devolviendo valores. Una manera de acceder al valor que retorna una función y mostrarlo de manera gráfica:

```
from tkinter import messagebox as mb #Ojo a la importación

def funcion():
    return "Mensaje!" #Seretorna un valor

mb.showinfo(message = funcion()) #Se usa la función como mensaje, ya que retorna un valor
```

Sucede:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Debido a que se retorna un valor, con solo invocar la función se accede al valor retornado. En tu caso en especifico es más eficiente "trasladar" (por así decirlo) las variables, ejecutando funciones dentro de funciones y usando estas variables como parámetros.

```
def calcular_Promedio():
    suma_notas = 0

    for i in range(5):
        try:
            nota = int(input('Ingrese el valor de la nota: '))
        except:
            print('Dato ingresado no válido!')
            print('Ejecuta nuevamente el programa')
            sys.exit()

        if nota < 0 and nota > 7:
            print('Nota fuera de rango')
            print('Ejecuta nuevamente el programa')
            sys.exit()
    
        suma_notas = suma_notas + nota
        promedio_final = suma_notas / 5

    if (promedio_final >= 4):
        estado = 'El alumno aprobo la asignatura con un promedio de {}'.format(promedio_final)
    else:
        estado = 'El alumno reprobo la asignatura con un promedio de {}'.format(promedio_final)

    Interfaz_Grafica(estado,promedio_final)
```

En este fragmento de código se ejecuta `Interfaz_grafica()` dentro de `calcular_Promedio()`, con los valores que se necesitan mostrar gráficamente.

**¿Ahora por dónde seguimos?**

Si invocamos `Interfaz_grafica()` con los parámetros a los que queremos acceder, podemos manipularlos en esta función:

```
def Interfaz_Grafica(estado: str,promedio_final: int):
    raiz = Tk() 
    raiz.geometry("350x350") #Cambio el tamaño para que el mensaje quepa
    raiz.resizable(0, 0)
    raiz.title("Interfaz gráfica para control de calificaciones")
    raiz.config(bg="White")

    #Esta parte no es necesaria realmente xD
    miFrame = Frame(raiz) 
    miFrame.pack()
    miFrame.config(bg = "White") 
    miFrame.config(width = "150", height = "50")
   
    Button(raiz, text="Calcular el promedio",command = lambda: Label(text = '{}. \nCon un promedio final de {}'.format(estado,promedio_final)).pack()).pack()
    raiz.mainloop()
```

Como se ve, en el `command` de botón se invoca una [`lambda`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#lambda-expressions), y esta invoca un `Label()` ya con su `pack()` hecho.

**¿Qué se obtiene con esto?**

Una ejecución de ejemplo que primero solicita los datos

```
Ingrese el valor de la nota: 3
Ingrese el valor de la nota: 4
Ingrese el valor de la nota: 6
Ingrese el valor de la nota: 5
Ingrese el valor de la nota: 7
```

y una interfaz gráfica que muestra un botón, que al presionarse muestra un mensaje

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Una gran observación:**

Tu código original es muy **redundante**, ejemplos las funciones `validar_dato()`, `validar_rango()` y `endex()`. Entiendo que se tenía la intención de manejar los errores/excepciones pero esto se podía hacer en la misma función. Esto se puede lograr ya que Python es un [lenguaje de programación interpretado](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Int%C3%A9rprete_(inform%C3%A1tica))! Se ejecuta linea por linea, y si hacemos las validaciones en orden no es necesario acudir a otras funciones.

**El código optimizado, solo dos funciones**

Con dos funciones, una para la solicitud de datos y otra para gráficar los datos, podemos conseguir el resultado deseado:

```
import sys
import tkinter.messagebox as mb
from tkinter import *

def Interfaz_Grafica(estado: str,promedio_final: int):
    raiz = Tk() 
    raiz.geometry("350x350") #Cambio el tamaño para que el mensaje quepa
    raiz.resizable(0, 0)
    raiz.title("Interfaz gráfica para control de calificaciones")
    raiz.config(bg="White")

    #Esta parte no es necesaria realmente xD
    miFrame = Frame(raiz) 
    miFrame.pack()
    miFrame.config(bg = "White") 
    miFrame.config(width = "150", height = "50")
   
    Button(raiz, text="Calcular el promedio",command = lambda: Label(text = '{}. \nCon un promedio final de {}'.format(estado,promedio_final)).pack()).pack()
    raiz.mainloop()


def calcular_Promedio():
    suma_notas = 0

    for i in range(5):
        try:
            nota = int(input('Ingrese el valor de la nota: '))
        except:
            print('Dato ingresado no válido!')
            print('Ejecuta nuevamente el programa')
            sys.exit()

        if nota < 0 and nota > 7:
            print('Nota fuera de rango')
            print('Ejecuta nuevamente el programa')
            sys.exit()
    
        suma_notas = suma_notas + nota
        promedio_final = suma_notas / 5

    if (promedio_final >= 4):
        estado = 'El alumno aprobo la asignatura con un promedio de {}'.format(promedio_final)
    else:
        estado = 'El alumno reprobo la asignatura con un promedio de {}'.format(promedio_final)

    Interfaz_Grafica(estado,promedio_final)

calcular_Promedio()
```

**Nota:** Hay que notar la zona que se comentó como *"Esta parte no es necesaria realmente xD"*, no es necesario definir un frame. Nuestra interfaz gráfica solo consta de dos elementos (el botón y el texto). En un caso hipotético el frame sirve para dividir el la ventana en varias partes y colocar widgets en **distintas partes**.

**La integridad del código original:**

Como ya dije, tu script en primera instancia era poco eficiente por la redundancia de las funciones, se vuelve más optimo el hacer las validaciones, manejo de errores/excepciones en una misma función.

Me despido,espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias estimado, de verdad me falta mucho que aprender de Python, agradezco todos tus consejos.

Comment: Si te funciono no olvides puntuarla y aceptarlo, si eso quieres. Con las flechas y la palomita de arriba. xD